# Why don't we need to inject a word non-colinear in this statement?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, mobius-transformation

I'm reading [Conway complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 48 he proves the following proposition:

> ***Proposition.*** If $z_2$, $z_3$, $z_4$ are distinct points in $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ and $\omega_2$, $\omega_3$, $\omega_4$ are also distinct points in $\mathbb{C}_\infty$, then there is one and only one Möbius transformation $S$ such that $S z_2 = \omega_2$, $S z_3 = \omega_3$, $S z_4 = \omega_4$.

Afterwards he made the following claim:

> It is well known from high school geometry that three points in the
>   plane determine a circle. (Recall that a circle in $\mathbb
>  C_{\infty}$ passing through $\infty$ corresponds to a straight line in
>   $\mathbb C$. **Hence there is no need to inject in the previous
>   statement the word "non-collinear."**) A straight line in the plane will
>   be called a circle. The next result explains when four points lie on
>   a circle.

I did understand everything he says except: "Hence there is no need to inject in the previous statement the word 'non-collinear'."

Could someone clarify this statement?